# Why, conceptually, is it that $\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n-1}{r-1} + \binom{n-1}{r}$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients, intuition

Why, conceptually, is it that $$\binom{n}{r} = \binom{n-1}{r-1} + \binom{n-1}{r}?$$ I know how to prove that this is true, but I don't understand conceptually why it makes sense.

Comment: This question have been asked here many times. Neither of the answer to those questions was satisfactory to you? http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86093/why-is-n1-choose-k-n-choose-k-n-choose-k-1, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/392595/whats-the-intuition-behind-this-equality-involving-combinatorics, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20475/proving-pascals-rule-n-choose-r-n-1-choose-r-1n-1-choose and many other questions list there among linked questions.

Comment: You could also have had a look at [frequent tab](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/binomial-coefficients?sort=frequent&pageSize=50) for the tag [tag:binomial-coefficients].

Comment: Those posts were mostly discussing proofs for why this equality is true. After reading them, I still didn't feel that I understood the intuition behind it. I'm sorry if this question seems repetitive.

Comment: But several of those posts have as one of the answers the same argument as in the answer you have accepted here...

Comment: The phrasing of the answer I accepted makes more sense to me than those. It is, however, possible that I might have missed an answer.

Comment: I agree 100% with Martin Sleziak and vote to close.

Comment: At this point, I have gotten the answer that I was looking for, so whether or not you close does not concern me.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sure.  You're dividing into 2 cases.  On the one hand you're saying I'm stuck choosing this element over here.  So now I have r-1 more choices to make out of n-1 things.  In the other case you're refusing that element.  Now you've eliminated a choice, but still must pick r elements.  These two cases are exhaustive and exclusive.

Answer (score 15):

Because the number of ways that we can make a team of a certain size is equal to the number of ways that we can make a team of the same size without Fred, plus the number of ways we can make a team of size one smaller, plus Fred.

Comment: dang.  A deluge of answers just fell.

Comment: @Slade: Please, can you explain [this similar identity](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880209/have-any-one-studied-this-binomial-like-coefficients-before) also. Thank you.

Comment: @Nilan The number of ways we can pick a team of $r$ people, and then name one of them Bob, equals the number of ways we can name one person Bob, and then pick a team of $r-1$ other people.  This generalizes to the case of more than one Bob.

Answer (score 8):

The number of the combination that we choose $r$ people from $n$ people is the sum of the number of the combination that a person named $A$ is included and the number of the combination that $A$ is not included.

Answer (score 4):

Another simple way to look at it is Pascal's triangle.  This is simply a formulation of the rule that governs the triangle -- an entry is the sum of the two entries above it.  The $i$-th entry in the $n$-th row is the sum of the $i-1$-th entry in the $n-1$-th row and the $i$-th entry in the $n-1$-th row.  Hence,
$$\binom{n-1}{i-1}+\binom{n-1}{i}=\binom{n}{i}$$

Comment: This presumes that Pascal's triangle means something for binomial coefficients...

Answer (score 2):

Consider picking $r$ objects out of a set of $n$ of them. Pick a particular object $O$. Either your set has $O$, or it doesn't. There are $\binom{n - 1}{r - 1}$ sets with $O$, and $\binom{n - 1}{r}$ sets without it. (Do you see why those are true?) So together, there are $\binom{n - 1}{r - 1} + \binom{n - 1}{r}$ sets of size $r$.

Answer (score 1):

The number of ways of choosing $r$ items from $n$ distinct items is the same as

- choosing $r-1$ items from the first $n-1$ items (and add to the last item), plus
- choosing $r$ items from the first $n-1$ items (and not choosing the last item)