# Proof of the combinatorial identity: $\frac{k+1}{k+1-i} {k+1-i \choose i} = \frac{k}{k-i} {k-i \choose i} + \frac{k-1}{k-i} {k-i-1 \choose i-1}$

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

I have been working on proving the following combinatorial identity:

$$\frac{k+1}{k+1-i} {k+1-i \choose i} = \frac{k}{k-i} {k-i \choose i} + \frac{k-1}{k-i} {k-i-1 \choose i-1}$$

and I would appreciate any guidance or insights.

I tried applying some well-known combinatorial identities such as Pascal's Identity and Vandermonde's Identity, but I couldn't figure out how to manipulate them to obtain the desired result.

Or maybe this equation is not true?

Thank you!

Comment: I don't think your identity is valid, take for example $k=4,i=2$. Left hand side gives $5$ but the right hand side gives $\frac{7}{2}$

Comment: You're right. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> $$\frac{k+1}{k+1-i} {k+1-i \choose i} = \frac{k}{k-i} {k-i \choose i} + \frac{k-1}{k-i} {k-i-1 \choose i-1}$$

The identity does not hold true in general, as noted in a comment already.

This looks related to OP's other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4695301/291201), which reduces to the slightly different (correct) identity:

$$\frac{k+1}{k-i+1} {k-i+1 \choose i} = \frac{k}{k-i} {k-i \choose i} + \frac{k-1}{k-i} {\color{red}{k-i} \choose i-1}$$

This combinatorial identity can be proved directly using that $\,\binom{m}{n} = \frac{m(m-1)\ldots(m-n+1)}{n!}\,$:

$$
\require{cancel}
\frac{k+1}{\xcancel{k-i+1}} \cdot\frac{\xcancel{(k-i+1)} \cdot \cancel{(k-i)\ldots(k-2i+2)}}{i \cdot \bcancel{(i-1)!}} \\= \frac{k}{k-i} \cdot\frac{\cancel{(k-i)\ldots(k-2i+2)} \cdot (k-2i+1)}{i \cdot \bcancel{(i-1)!}} + \frac{k-1}{k-i} \cdot \frac{\cancel{(k-i)\ldots(k-2i+2)}}{\bcancel{(i-1)!}}
\\ \iff\qquad \frac{k+1}{i} = \frac{k(k-2i+1)}{(k-i)i} + \frac{k-1}{k-i}
\\ \iff\qquad (k+1)(k-i) = k(k-2i+1) +(k-1)i \qquad\iff\qquad \ldots
$$

Other proofs can be found under the [Has anyone studied this binomial like coefficients before?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/880209/has-anyone-studied-this-binomial-like-coefficients-before)