# Need help finding mistakes in my proof about Dickson polynomials

Tags: polynomials

I've been working on a proof involving Dickson polynomials, and I'm having trouble finding any mistakes and completing this proof.

We have the equality \begin{equation}
    D_n(x, a)=\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{n}{2}\rfloor}d_{n,i}x^{n-2i} \  \text{, where} \ d_{n,i}=\frac{n}{n-i}{n-i\choose i}(-a)^i.
\end{equation}
It simplifies to the conditions that $$D_n(x,a)=x^n-nax^{n-2}+ \cdots + \frac{n}{2}^2(-a)^{(n/2)-1}x^2+2(-a)^{n/2},$$ when $n$ is an even number, and $$D_n(x,a)=x^n-nax^{n-2}+ \cdots + \frac{n}{2}^2(-a)^{(n/2)-1}x,$$ for odd values of $n$.

We will prove this expression using mathematical induction.
Let's check if the equality holds for $n = 1$ and $n = 2$.
For $n = 1$:
$$
D_1(x, a) = x.
$$
According to the equality:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{1}{2}\rfloor}d_{1,i}x^{1-2i} = d_{1,0}x^1 = x,
$$
which is true.
For $n = 2$:
$$
D_2(x, a) = x^2 - 2ax.
$$
According to the equality:
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{2}{2}\rfloor}d_{2,i}x^{2-2i} = d_{2,0}x^2 + d_{2,1}x^0 = x^2 - 2ax,
$$
which is also true.
Assume that the equality holds for $n = k$ and $n = k - 1$. Now, we will show that the equality also holds for $n = k + 1$.
Dickson polynomials satisfy the recursive relation:
$$
D_{k+1}(x, a) = xD_k(x, a) - aD_{k-1}(x, a).
$$
Substituting the expressions for $D_k(x, a)$ and $D_{k-1}(x, a)$, we have:
$$
D_{k+1}(x, a) = x\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\rfloor}d_{k,i}x^{k-2i} - a\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{k-1}{2}\rfloor}d_{k-1,i}x^{k-1-2i}.
$$
Now, transform the sums so that they can be added together, taking into account the index shifts.
$$
D_{k+1}(x, a) = \sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{k}{2}\rfloor}d_{k,i} x^{k+1-2i} - a\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor \frac{k-1}{2}\rfloor} d_{k-1,i} x^{k-1-2i+2}.
$$
Next, we obtain:
$$
D_{k+1}(x, a) = d_{k,0}x^{k+1} + \sum_{i=1}^{\lfloor \frac{k+1}{2}\rfloor} [d_{k,i} x^{k+1-2i} - a d_{k-1,i-1} x^{k+1-2i}].
$$
To complete the proof, we need to show that $d_{k+1,i} = d_{k,i} - a d_{k-1,i-1}$.
Using the definition of $d_{n,i}$:
$$d_{n,i} = \frac{n}{n-i} {n-i \choose i} (-a)^i$$
Substitute the values for $d_{k+1,i}$, $d_{k,i}$, and $d_{k-1,i-1}$:
$$\frac{k+1}{k+1-i} {k+1-i \choose i} (-a)^i = \frac{k}{k-i} {k-i \choose i} (-a)^i - a \frac{k-1}{k-i} {k-i-1 \choose i-1} (-a)^{i-1}$$

And i don't know what next.

Comment: What polynomial???? Dickson???

Comment: Yes, $D_n(x,a)$ is a Dickson polynomial

Comment: You have made an error somewhere, since substituting values for $k$ and $i$ (for example, $k=5$ and $i=2$), the final equation is not an equality.

Comment: Yes, I know and I can't find

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Substitute the values for $d_{k+1,i}$, $d_{k,i}$, and $d_{k-1,i-1}$:
> $$\frac{k+1}{k+1-i} {k+1-i \choose i} (-a)^i = \frac{k}{k-i} {k-i \choose i} (-a)^i - a \frac{k-1}{k-i} {k-i-1 \choose i-1} (-a)^{i-1}$$

The last term is wrong, it should be $\displaystyle\,d_{k-1,i-1} = \frac{k-1}{k-i}\binom{\color{red}{k-i}}{i-1}(-a)^{i-1}\,$ instead.

Correcting that, and canceling a factor of $(-a)^{i}$ the equality to prove becomes:

$$\frac{k+1}{k-i+1} {k-i+1 \choose i} = \frac{k}{k-i} {k-i \choose i} + \frac{k-1}{k-i} {k-i \choose i-1}$$

This is a simple combinatorial identity that can be proved with standard techniques.