# Confused by algebraic manipulation in a proof relatied to binomial thereom

Tags: algebra-precalculus

[image]

At the second line we get two fractions with unlike denominators.  To add them, I thought you'd need to get them to the common denominator `(n-k)!k!(n-k+1)!(k-1)!`

But instead, the proof does three things that confuse me:

1) the green fraction is only multiplied by `(n-k+1)/(n-k+1)`.   I expected `((n-k+1)!(k-1)!)/((n-k+1)!(k-1)!)`

2) the yellow fraction is only multiplied by `k/k`.  I expected `((n-k)!k!)/((n-k)!k!)`

3) After multiplying those green and yellow fractions by those terms,  you are still left with two fractions with unlike denominators [unless I'm not seeing how to simplify].  I don't see how he winds up with the expression in the purple box.

Ugh. I'm probably making some very obvious Algebra mistake, but I cannot see it.

(this proof came from a [different stackoverflow question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/86093/why-is-n1-choose-k-n-choose-k-n-choose-k-1) I was interested in)

Comment: Second line: $k!=k (k-1)!$.

Comment: $(n-k+1)=(n-(k-1))$ which is the next after $(n-k)$. (Compare $n-5$ with $n-4=n-(5-1)$).

Comment: Thus : $(n-k+1)(n-k)!=(n-k+1)!$.

Comment: Conclusion : after the "manipulations" in 2nd and 3rd lines, the two fractions have the same denominator.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Oh yes, I see it now and it makes perfect sense.  Sigh.  I am really awful at recognising to do these kind of manipulations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The factorials have lots of common terms.  $(k-1)!$ is the product of all the numbers from $k-1$ down to $1$ while $k!$ is the product of all the numbers from $k$ down to $1$, so we have $k!=k(k-1)!$.  Similarly we have $(n-k+1)!=(n-k+1)(n-k)!$  That is why they multiplied top and bottom by $n-k+1$ in the first term and $k$ in the second going from the second line to the third.  From the third to the fourth they used the earlier relations, which get the two fractions over a common denominator.

Comment: yeah, I totally missed the `k! = k(k-1)!` strategy.  I don't know how to become more adept at this sort of stuff. It's very frustrating when I face proof exercises.